# Problem to print all values of Priority queue of pairs in C++

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the function of printing second element(of pair) of priority queue :

```
void show(priority_queue <pair<int,string>> pq)
{
    priority_queue <pair<int,string>> tmp=pq;
    while (!tmp.empty())
    {
        cout<<tmp.top().second<<endl;
        tmp.pop();
    }
}
```

Input values are:

```
1 www.youtube.com 
2 www.google.com 
3 www.google.com.hk
10 www.alibaba.com 
5 www.taobao.com 
10 www.bad.com 
7 www.good.com 
8 www.fudan.edu.cn 
9 www.university.edu.cn 
10 acm.university.edu.cn
```

I know it should sort according to  first element in descending order and when two elements are same then it keep the element first which I enter first.

It should print "www.alibaba.com" first then "www.bad.com" and then "acm.university.edu.cn" because the first value for all is 10.

But it prints "www.bad.com" first then "www.alibaba.com" and then "acm.university.edu.cn" and so on. What is the wrong here?

Comment: On an unrelated note, since you pass the queue by value into the function `pq` will already be a copy of the original and you don't need yet another copy with `tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::pair` [comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) uses lexiographical comparion.

For two pairs `p1` and `p2` it means that if `p1.first == p2.first` then it compares  `p1.second < p2.second`. So the order will be "largest" `second` to "smallest" (since priority queues does reverse ordering).

If you want custom comparison then you could provide a custom "less than" function for the queue. For example one that doesn't compare the `second` member of the pair (but then I think the order will be *indeterminate*).

Comment: If it is right it should print "acm.university.edu.cn" first..so why "www.www.bad.com" print first.

Comment: @ImtiazMehedi Because it does *reverse* ordering. The "highest" value will be on top. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Someprogrammerdude is correct. To explain why in more detail, here is the full output, if you print both members of the pair:

```
10, www.bad.com
10, www.alibaba.com
10, acm.university.edu.cn
9, www.university.edu.cn
8, www.fudan.edu.cn
7, www.good.com
5, www.taobao.com
3, www.google.com.hk
2, www.google.com
1, www.youtube.com
```

Perhaps it is more obvious if we use a simpler dataset (1-4 paired with a,b,c):

```
4, c
4, b
4, a
3, c
3, b
3, a
2, c
2, b
2, a
1, c
1, b
1, a
```

The missing piece can be supplied by [cppreference.com - priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) (emphasis by me)

> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides constant time
>   lookup of the **largest (by default)** element, at the expense of
>   logarithmic insertion and extraction.
>
> A user-provided Compare can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g.
>   using std::greater would cause the smallest element to appear as
>   the top().